# springboot application cant make connection with sql database that runs on docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, phpmyadmin, yaml

I had a project which was running in localhost with no issues with intellij as the Springboot instance, SQL with Xampp. This was working fine. But now i want to delpoy all of it on docker. So i made a dockerfile and a docker-compose up file in my directorys as so :

```
-Application
 |
  -Frontend (not in docker implemented yet)
  -Backend (springAPI)
   |
    -dockerfile
  -Python (flaskAPI) (not in docker implemented yet)
docker-compose.yml
```

The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <pass>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: <user>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <pass>
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  spring-api:
    image: spring-api:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  dbdata:
  mysql-data:
```

And the dockerfile for the springapi looks like this:

```
# Use an official OpenJDK runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the application jar file to the container
COPY build/libs/backendAPI.jar backendAPI.jar

# Run the application
CMD ["java", "-jar", "backendAPI.jar"]
```

This can be docker composed up and it runs the containers. How ever the java spring boot throws an error and shuts down. The error is:

```
`2023-03-06T12:25:37.603Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2023-03-06T12:25:38.685Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.


com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`
```

i tried to reconfigure my application.settings like so :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/mydb
spring.datasource.username=<theusername>
spring.datasource.password=<thepassword>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

But to no avail. Since it keeps throwing the same error. The SQL server is accesable through the url given. So that is running fine (except for not having admin previlage, but thats a different problem.)

This setup with some tweaks to the application.settings worked fine when i was just using Xammp and intellij. But now i cannot get it to connect. What am i missing here ?

**edit what i tried so far**

```
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: sql-db
```

and then changed the application.settings with:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sql-db:8888/mydb (and also with sql-db:3306)
```

but that still gives the same errors.

Comment: your db is now accessible by domain `db`. Not `localhost`..

Comment: changed it, but the error still seems to presist, could there be a setting that is wrong somewhere else in the files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your DB service a container name in the docker compose file

```
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    **container_name: db-container**
```

Then in your jdbc url you should be referencing the configured database container name and the actual configured port for the database container.

So your datasource.url would look like

```
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db-container:3306/mydb
```

Comment: added both ```restart: always
    container_name: sql-db```
and ```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sql-db:3306/mydb```

deleted all the previous containers and rebuild everything. However the error still persists

Comment: You made sure to rebuild your java spring application and generate a new jar "backendAPI.jar" to be repackaged in your docker container?

Comment: Oh i did not ! I did now and it indeed fixes my issue ! Thanks. 
If i may ask a follow up question. Do i need to rebuild the entire container everytime i update the springAPI ? or can i run the ``` ./gradlew bootJar``` to update the jar file and then force recreate the springAPI container ?

Comment: The force create is not really needed.  That just makes sure docker compose actually does not reuse the existing containers.  You need to make sure when you make a change to your backend you recreate the application jar "./gradlew bootJar" and then that you update your docker image "docker build ..." .  Obviously if you change java source code you will need to make sure gradle recompiles, jut doesn't repackage. 
Then you can just "docker compose down", "docker compose up".

Comment: You do not need the `container_name:` setting; the Compose service name `db` is usable as a host name as well.